# Restrict direct URL access to files with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, url-rewriting

I've been looking around for a good answer to this, but I can't seem to find an answer that really works for me. It's a pretty simple question.

I'd like to restrict users from accessing a specific file like this:

`https://www.example.com/styles/homestyles.css`

Though I would like `homestyles.css` to still be accessible by the website. All solutions I have found so far seem to block all access to `homestyles.css` which causes the website to load with no styling.

I've tried using `Options -Indexes` in my `.htaccess` file, which returns a 403 error when the user tries to access `https://www.example.com/styles`, though files inside the `/styles` directory are still accessible.

What is the best way to do this using `.htaccess`?

Comment: Questions like this are asked quite often, however that shows some common miss conception about how the web works. If you publish something then what is the idea behind trying to hold it back at the same time? _Why?_ What is so horrible in someone accessing that file if you have published it anyway? And _please_ don't try to answer this with something like "my intellectual property" ;-)

Comment: @arkascha I was just using a .css file as an example for the sake of simplicity. This was just a question as I was trying to see if it is "professional" to allow users to access files in this way, or if I _should_ be restricting access to certain files (like image files) via URL?

Comment: OK, so you actually ask a different question... In general one should only publish such documents / files / objects / whatever that are _meant_ to be published. Once published there is no sense in then trying to hold them back. That is true for the "world wide web", not for internal things like company webs and the like. However: such restrictions, if implemented, are not based on dynamic configuration files of the http server (".htaccess"). Instead you use a routing script to allow access to such objects. In there you can do whatever you want to decide if you want to grant access or not...

Comment: @arkascha Okay got it, Thanks.